# Remove placeholder span after form submitted

Tags: jquery

I'm using a placeholder span in my input fields. Using jQuery, I show/hide the span depending on whether there is a value entered into the field. The problem: When I implement this type of placeholder in a form, after submitting the form the span isn't hidden, despite the presence of a value in the input field. After the search is performed, the value remains as does the placeholder. Is there a way to correct that so the placeholder is hidden? Here is the jQuery I'm using:

```
$(function() {
    $("span.holder + input").keyup(function() {
        if($(this).val().length) {
            $(this).prev('span.holder').hide();
        } else {
            $(this).prev('span.holder').show();
        }
    });
    $("span.holder").click(function() {
        $(this).next().focus();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be missing part of the picture, but what I'm imagining is that the page reloads. This will mean that there is no input placeholders with "hidden" state anymore, making all placeholders visible. Yet at the same time, the browser is remembering the field value so it is visible, too.

If my guess is right, you just need some quick and easy extra logic inside your ready function:

```
$('input').each(function() {
    $input = $(this);
    if($input.val().length > 0) {
    $input.prev('span').hide();
    }
});
```